# A PHPUnit Testing Strategy for Zend Application

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I have been developing a typical blog-style application in Zend.  So far I have been getting by on minimal testing, but now I need to bullet proof things and I'm chasing some advice or tips on my unit testing strategy.

Models:

- To test models, I have been extending PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.  This seems to work fine.
- I have read up on Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase, however I'm not sure where I would use this?  I thought it might negate the need for me to drop/create the DB between each test, but that doesn't seem to be the case?
- Dropping/creating the DB between each test has become quite painful because I have a lot of test data.  Is there any easy way to deal with this (e.g. mock the DB?), or should I be cutting down on my test data?  (At the moment I am simply calling `exec('mysql < TestSetup.sql --user=root --password=password')` in the setUp() method of my test cases).

Controllers and Views:

- To test controllers and views I am extending Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase.  This seems to work fine.
- Again, setting up/tearing down seems to be the biggest bug bear.  I was considering removing that step, and only using asserts that were unaffected by changes in db content.  Is this a common practice?

Your thoughts are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-with-the-zend-framework-with-zend_test-and-phpunit/2009/06/